# what controls the time a request is processed on an apache2.2/php5 web service

Tags: php

I'm testing a web service that is running on Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.  Using curl to send requests I see that the time spent is always 2 minutes.  I'm only getting partial returns from the service and I think something is configured to stop after 2 minutes.

A search of httpd.config and php.ini for the string 120 turned up nothing.

What could be set to 2 minutes to produce this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP caps all scripts to a time limit, which is configurable at runtime (see [set_time_limit](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), for example) or through php.ini (max_execution_time directive). That's likely what's got you - your time limit is set to two minutes.

Comment: Each call to set_time_limit sets the counter to 0. So if you have a loop, and you call set_time_limit(60) at the head of the loop, you are effectively limit the time limit of each loop iteration to 60 seconds. (Of course that's a basic example)